# Background changed with slider - WHY does this work on jsFiddle, but not on a real site

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, slider, jsfiddle

This is a copy of my latest work on jsfiddle, but I cannot for the life of me get it to work on my live site. Is there a conflict of js with Wordpress? It is super frustrating. Can anyone take a look at my code and figure out what I may have missed here?

HTML:

```
<input id="dwe" type="range" min="1" max="10" step="1" value="5">
<div id="main" class="super-wrapper">
</div>
```

JS:

```
var slidez = document.getElementById('dwe');
document.getElementById("main").addEventListener("click", function(){
document.getElementById("main").style.backgroundImage = "url(http://www.designwithenergy.com/images/backgrounds/rotator.php)";
});
slidez.onchange = function() {
  document.getElementById("main").style.backgroundImage = "url(http://www.designwithenergy.com/images/backgrounds/rotator" + this.value + ".php)";


}
```

CSS:

```
#main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 10px;

  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

body {
  color: #CCC !important;
  text-shadow: #000 -2px 2px 2px;
```

}

http://jsfiddle.net/Opticalfuel/9rokvnnf/148/

If required I can place it on my life site and share a link, but first let me know if I am missing something obvious in the code that would prevent it running on a fairly standard install of Wordpress.

Actual js code I am trying in `<head> code... </head>` and after `<body>` tag, and right before `</body>`  all with NO success. (site still will not reproduce results and function I proved SHOULD be working using jsFiddle.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var slidez = document.getElementById('dwe');
document.getElementById("main").addEventListener("click", function()     {document.getElementById("main").style.backgroundImage = "url(http://www.designwithenergy.com/images/backgrounds/rotator.php)";});
slidez.onchange = function(){document.getElementById("main").style.backgroundImage = "url(http://www.designwithenergy.com/images/backgrounds/rotator" + this.value + ".php)";}

</script>
```

Comment: jsfiddle has a ["load type" option](http://prntscr.com/9r86pr) for JS, which you have set to "onDomready". Your script works with all of the options except "No wrap - in <head>". Is it possible that this is where the script is placed on your site?

Comment: Ok. I think I might know what you are referring to, but so I can be sure, can you tell me if you are saying: that in order to use the Javascript... I need the function to wait for the DOM to be ready? what would I need to modify or where would you recommend I place that code (header or footer) or in Body so that it is going to let it work?

Comment: Ok. Tried placing the js code in the header (i.e. between <head> and </head> tags, and also right after the <body> tag and right before the </body> tag. In each case I am using:

Comment: Put the JavaScript in a function; call this function from within the onload event.